# linear interpolation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have 2 numpy arrays

```
X = [[2 3 6], [7 2 9], [7 1 4]]
a = [0  0.0005413307    0.0010949014    0.0015468832    0.0027740823    0.0033288284]
b = [0  0.0050251256    0.0100502513    0.0150753769    0.0201005025    0.0251256281]

new = []
for z in range(3):
     new.append(interp1d(a, z[0], b, 'linear'))
```

I am getting error as  :

```
    if xi is not None and shape[axis] != len(xi):
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

I need to find the linear interpolation of the same. How can I find that?

I have values X with respect to time a but I want to find interpolation for time b.
Linear interpolation will give me 3 points as in X for every a[i] and b[i] ?

Comment: interp1d has different signature, check the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html

Answer (score 3):

You put the arguments in wrong order. Flowing is the help message of interp1d, check it out:

> ```
> interp1d(x, y, kind='linear', axis=-1, copy=True, bounds_error=True,fill_value=np.nan)
> ```
>
> Interpolate a 1-D function.
>
> `x` and `y` are arrays of values used to approximate some function f:
>   `y = f(x)` .
>
> This class returns a function whose call method uses interpolation
>   to find the value of new points.

Comment: I will get a object after this stage. how will I use that object to get values?

Answer (score 2):

`interp1d` is a function whose return value is a new function. This new function can then be called with values in the given interpolation range:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x1 = [ 0.,          0.04007922,  0.04723573,  0.05440107,  0.06178645,  0.06837938]
x2 = [ 0.,          0.00502513,  0.01005025,  0.01507538,  0.0201005,   0.02512563]
f = interp1d(x1, x2)

f([0.0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.068])
#array([ 0.        ,  0.0012538 ,  0.0025076 ,  0.0037614 ,  0.02483647])
```

Comment: can you explain me why and how u consider this values? f([0.0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.068])

Comment: `f` is a function where `x2 = f(x1)` by means of interpolation. Thus `f(0.0)` returns `0.0` and `f(0.068)` returns `~0.24`. Don't get confused by the vectorized notation. What you do is pass a list of values to `f` and in return you'll get back a list of values where `f` has been applied to each individual value in the list. `x1` should be named `x` and `x2` should be named `y`, so that `y = f(x)` as mentioned in the docs. Hope that helps.

Comment: according to your explanation I v updated the question. you mean to say that I have to pass X somewhere? I didnt understood how you took value 0.068.
can you explain with updated question?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. What are `X`, `a` and `b` in your case? What is your data? In my example `0.068` is just a made up number to show that the interpolation works. Maybe you can give us an example of expected inputs and expected outputs.